# I can't install ubuntu 14.04.1 on my pc

Tags: boot, nvidia

I am trying to install ubuntu on my pc but i can't.I can't find what problems are.
Booting from dvd and getting to the purple screen and after that installing ubuntu,but it goes to black screen with a cursor blinking and nothing happens.
My PC Spec:
Mainboard:Foxconn H61AP-S
cpu:Intel Celeron G460
ram:Kingmax 4 GBs DDR3
VGA:Nvidia Geforce 210
HDD:1TB Toshiba
i have winodws 7 64bit installed on my pc.by the way, i tried many ways.nomodeset, noalpic, acpi=off and others.and also tried installing from USB, But outcome was the same.

Comment: The above answer is a bit long, but should give you tons of solutions too!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Download Ubuntu Minimal 32 bits:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

You must  burn it into a bootable CD.

Make sure your PC is connected to a lan network, insert the cd into your cdrom and boot up your computer from the cdrom and select: --- Install.

Comment: Would you tell me what that version is?Can i download the 64bits?or i have to download just 32bits to get around this problem.Thanks for answering